# How would I duplicate this plot and table in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting

I have struggled trying to duplicate this graphic from [Spurious correlations](http://www.tylervigen.com/spurious-correlations) using `ListLinePlot`, but I cannot get the tick options to display the year for every data point. I suspect there is a simple way to display the table, but I don't know where to start

[image: math]

Here is what I have:

```
y = Range[2000, 2009]; 
d = {5, 4.7, 4.6, 4.4, 4.3, 4.1, 4.2, 4.2, 4.2, 4.1}; 
m = {8.2, 7, 6.5, 5.3, 5.2, 4, 4.6, 4.5, 4.2, 3.7}; 

ListLinePlot [d, PlotStyle -> {ColorData[97, 1]}, ImagePadding -> {{50, 50}, {20, 20}}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1/4, ImageSize -> Large, Axes -> False, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}, 
  Ticks -> {{2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009}, {4.0, 5.0}}, 
  FrameTicks -> {None, All, None, None}, 
  Frame -> {True, True, False, False}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Please show us what you have a tried. Also, check out `Column` and `Grid`.

Comment: Also provide raw data, you should not expect us to manually enter all of the data.

Comment: see also [DateListPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DateListPlot.html)

Comment: You will also be interested in [Plot with multiple Y-axes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/164846/27951).

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks. That is exactly what I have been trying to do, but I cannot get the x-axis to have a label for every data point, so all the years display properly

Comment: Website: http://tylervigen.com/spurious-correlations. Oddly morbid

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
{mscale, dscale} = MinMax /@ {m, d}  
rescaledm = Rescale[m, mscale, dscale];
mticks =  Charting`FindTicks[dscale, mscale]; 

DateListPlot[{d, rescaledm}, {2000}, Joined -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, mticks}, {DateRange[{2000}, {2009}, "Year"], Automatic}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice and concise

Comment: @Brian, thank you for the accept.

Comment: Why is the last blue data point (for 2009) missing?

Comment: I think the last blue edge is only hidden by the last yellow one.

Comment: @Brian, as Henrik noted, it is there but hidden behind the yellow line. You can try something like `PlotStyle->{ Directive[Opacity[.7],Thickness[.02]], Thick}` to see both lines.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I don't think so. The last 'd' value is 4.1, and the last 'm' value is 3.7

Comment: @kglr OK, I get it. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

This might take you closer to you goal:

```
y = Range[2000, 2009];
d = {5, 4.7, 4.6, 4.4, 4.3, 4.1, 4.2, 4.2, 4.2, 4.1};
m = {8.2, 7, 6.5, 5.3, 5.2, 4, 4.6, 4.5, 4.2, 3.7};
mticks = Range[3, 9];
{scale, shift} = NArgMin[Total[(d - (s m + b))^2], {s, b}];
mscaled = (scale m + shift);
ListLinePlot[
 {
  Transpose[{y, d}],
  Transpose[{y, mscaled}]
  },
 ImagePadding -> {{50, 50}, {20, 20}},
 AspectRatio -> 1/4,
 ImageSize -> Large,
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14},
 FrameTicks -> {
   {Range[4, 5, 0.2], Transpose[{scale mticks + shift, mticks}]},
   {y, None}
   },
 Frame -> {{True, True}, {True, False}},
 InterpolationOrder -> 3,
 PlotMarkers -> None
 ]
```

[image]

The format for `FrameTicks` and `Frame` is always `{{left,right},{bottom,top}}`. Note also how you can introduce "fake" ticks on the right hand side with `Transpose[{scale mticks + shift, mticks}]`: first entry in each sublist is the actual tick position; second entry is what is shown to the beholder.

I was also a bit puzzled that we cannot specify the x-axis' ticks arbitrarily. But the point is that without explicit x-coodinates, `ListLinePlot` assumes the x-coordinates to run from 1 to 10 for the list `d` has length 10. So, we actually *can* enforce that x-ticks are only plotted at positions specified by `y = Range[2000, 2009]` --- but the ticks will then be way outside the plot range and hence invisible.

Comment: That is great! I get that you need to scale and shift the 'm' data to plot on the same graph as the 'd' data, but I don't understand the mechanics of what line 4 is doing.

Comment: Very nice. Instead of the `Minimize`, I'd suggest `NArgMin[...]` here, which would return the list of optimized parameters directly. The result is the same, of course.

Comment: Very good point. Thanks!

Comment: When I run the code in a new notebook, I get this error, and the right side ticks don't display: 
Transpose::nmtx: The first two levels of {3.30863 +0.201386 mticks,mticks} cannot be transposed.

Comment: Sorry. Fixed it. Please try again.

Comment: Works great, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.