# Plot three vertical axes

Tags: plotting

I am trying to make a plot with 3 vertical axes (frame with three labels). The desired plot done in other software is as follow.

[image]

Here is my code for Mathematica.

```
    dAta = Table[{i, RandomReal[{1, 5}], 20, RandomReal[{50, 80}]}, {i, 
    100}];
tEstPt1 = 
 ListPlot[#, ImageSize -> 400, Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, True}},
     FrameTicks -> {{True, None}, {True, True}}(*All*), 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 6.0}}, Joined -> True, 
    PlotStyle -> Blue, ImagePadding -> {{60, 65}, {60, 10}}, 
    Axes -> False, 
    FrameStyle -> {{Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[0.75], 12] , 
       Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[0.75], 12]}, {Directive[
        Black, AbsoluteThickness[0.75], 12] , 
       Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[0.75], 12]}},
    FrameTicksStyle -> {{Directive[Black, Bold, 12, 
        AbsoluteThickness[0.75]], 
       Directive[Black, Bold, 12, 
        AbsoluteThickness[0.75]]}, {Directive[Black, Bold, 12, 
        AbsoluteThickness[0.75]], 
       Directive[Black, Bold, 12, AbsoluteThickness[0.75]]}}, 
    FrameLabel -> {{Style[#, Black, Bold, 14] &@("Y-label"), 
       None}, {Style[#, Black, Bold, 14] &@("X-label"), 
       None}} ] &@(dAta[[1 ;; 100, {1, 2}]])
tEstPt2 = 
 ListPlot[#, ImageSize -> 400, 
    Frame -> {{False, True}, {False, False}}, 
    FrameTicks -> {{False, All}, {False, False}}(*All*), 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 40.0}}, Joined -> True, 
    PlotStyle -> Green, ImagePadding -> {{60, 65}, {60, 10}}, 
    Axes -> False, 
    FrameStyle -> {{Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[0.75], 12] , 
       Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[0.75], 12]}, {Directive[
        Black, AbsoluteThickness[0.75], 12] , 
       Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[0.75], 12]}},
    FrameTicksStyle -> {{Directive[Black, Bold, 12, 
        AbsoluteThickness[0.75]], 
       Directive[Black, Bold, 12, 
        AbsoluteThickness[0.75]]}, {Directive[Black, Bold, 12, 
        AbsoluteThickness[0.75]], 
       Directive[Black, Bold, 12, AbsoluteThickness[0.75]]}}, 
    FrameLabel -> {{None, 
       Style[#, Black, Bold, 14] &@("Y1-label")}, {None, 
       None}} ] &@(dAta[[1 ;; 100, {1, 3}]])
tEstPt3 = 
 ListPlot[#, ImageSize -> 400, 
    Frame -> {{False, True}, {False, False}}, 
    FrameTicks -> {{False, All}, {False, False}}(*All*), 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {20, 90.0}}, Joined -> True, 
    PlotStyle -> Red, ImagePadding -> {{60, 65}, {60, 10}}, 
    PlotRangePadding -> {{0, 20}, {0, 0}}, Axes -> False, 
    FrameStyle -> {{Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[0.75], 12] , 
       Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[0.75], 12]}, {Directive[
        Black, AbsoluteThickness[0.75], 12] , 
       Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[0.75], 12]}},
    FrameTicksStyle -> {{Directive[Black, Bold, 12, 
        AbsoluteThickness[0.75]], 
       Directive[Black, Bold, 12, 
        AbsoluteThickness[0.75]]}, {Directive[Black, Bold, 12, 
        AbsoluteThickness[0.75]], 
       Directive[Black, Bold, 12, AbsoluteThickness[0.75]]}}, 
    FrameLabel -> {{None, 
       Style[#, Black, Bold, 14] &@("Y2-label")}, {None, 
       None}} ] &@(dAta[[1 ;; 100, {1, 4}]])
Overlay[{tEstPt1, tEstPt2, tEstPt3}]
```

The axes on the right are overlapping instead of offsetting. The main problem is offsetting the axes.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate: [Plot with multiple Y-axes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/164846/125)

Comment: Thank you for your link. It is true that the question is duplicate.