# Combining two plots with separate frame tick styles

Tags: plotting, frame

There are numerous questions here on combining two plots (usually ListPlots), but (as far as I can see) none with quite what I seek.  I would like to make a single plot consisting of two functions, each with the same abscissa (x range) but different ordinates (y range), in both offset and scale.  I want the left Frame axis to be in one style (blue) and the right Frame axis to be in another (red).  Inserting is extremely awkward because the spatial extents of the tick labels, offsets, scales, padding, and so on all differ.

Here is how far I've gotten:

```
pt1 = Plot[1 + Sin[x], {x, 1, 5},
  PlotRange -> {0, 3},
  PlotStyle -> Blue,
  Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}},
  FrameStyle -> {{Blue, None}, {Black, None}}]
```

[image]

```
pt2 = Plot[80 + 50 Cos[x^2],
  {x, 1, 5},
  PlotRange -> {1, All},
  AxesOrigin -> {1, 20},
  PlotStyle -> Red,
  Frame -> {{False, True}, {True, False}},
  FrameStyle -> {{None, Red}, {Black, None}},
  FrameTicks -> {{None, Range[20, 140, 10]}, {Automatic, None}}]
```

[image]

I would like to combine these into a single plot, where the left frame axis goes from 0 to 3 while the right axis goes from 20 to 120.  That is, the same height in the graph should correspond to 0 on the left and 20 on the right, and the same height in the graph should correspond to 3 on the left and 120 on the right.

`Show[pt1,pt2]` simply does not work:

[image]

I can change aspect ratios and offsets *by hand* but surely there is a more direct way.

Comment: related: [Plot with multiple Y-axes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/164846/125)

Comment: @kglr:  Yes, related... but without addressing my problem of offsets.  And all this awkward and arbitrary image padding to be done by hand.

Comment: maybe something like: ``r1 = {0, 3};
r2 = {20, 140};
Plot[{1 + Sin[x], Rescale[80 + 50 Cos[x^2], r2, r1]}, {x, 1, 5}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 3}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, 
 Frame -> {{True, True}, {True, False}},
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Charting`FindTicks[r1, r2][##] &}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
 FrameStyle -> {{Blue, Red}, {Black, None}}]``?

Comment: My understanding is that two x-axes should exist in the image, since 0 on the left is not the same as 20 on the right, is this correct?

Comment: Related [MultipleAxesListPlot](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MultipleAxesListPlot).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [`CombinePlots`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CombinePlots) [`ResourceFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ResourceFunction.html) to do all the work for you:

```
pt1 = Plot[1 + Sin[x], {x, 1, 5},
  PlotRange -> {0, 3},
  PlotStyle -> Blue,
  Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}},
  FrameStyle -> {{Blue, None}, {Black, None}}]

pt2 = Plot[80 + 50 Cos[x^2],
  {x, 1, 5},
  PlotRange -> {20, All},
  AxesOrigin -> {1, 20},
  PlotStyle -> Red,
  Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}},
  FrameStyle -> {{Red, None}, {Black, None}},
  FrameTicks -> {{{#,#}&/@Range[20, 140, 10], Automatic}, {Automatic, None}}]

ResourceFunction["CombinePlots"][pt1, pt2, "AxesSides" -> "TwoY"]
```

[image]

Note that the frame of `pt2` is on the left side - `CombinePlots` automatically moves it to the right. Also note that I am converting the list of tick positions `{x1, x2, ...}` into a list of the form `{{x1, lbl1}, {x2, lbl2}, ...}` - this is necessary due to a bug in the current version of `CombinePlots`<sup>1</sup>. Note also that I have set the `PlotRange` of `pt2` to `{20, All}` to align the `0` on the left axis with the `20` on the right one.

You can look at [the documentation](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CombinePlots) for details on the options and other examples. Some of the advantages of the approach used by `CombinePlots` are:

- It returns a single `Graphics` expression without any insets, and no `Overlay`. This makes it easier to process the expression futher.
- Accepts arbitrary graphics expressions, and is thus not limited to e.g. a two-axis `ListPlot`
- It is fairly easy to use (that is at least the intention): Essentially, `CombinePlots` is `Show` with a few additional options for more advanced combining features

<sup>1</sup> I have submitted a fixed version and will update this answer once it has been published. In the meantime, you can get the fixed version as `ResourceFunction[CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/langl/DeployedResources/Function/CombinePlots"]]`

Comment: LukasLang:  This is *SOO* useful!  (How did I not know about this?)  Thanks so very very much.  ($\color{green} \checkmark$) . Wait:  the height of $0$ on the left should be $20$ on the right.  How to fix that?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I'm wondering the same, how can this be accepted when 20 on the right is not zero on the left, and 120 on the right is not 3 on the left?

Comment: I accepted too quickly... but then figured it out on my own... by simply setting the PlotRanges appropriately.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork ah, so you don't want the axis on the right to extend outside of the plot to the left then. That's how I interpreted the question... I was trying to get at that in my question in my other comment. Oh well. Then I will undelete my deleted answer since I suppose that solves the question as well then.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Setting the `PlotRange` is indeed the way to go - I have also updated the answer to reflect this. The reason for the behavior is that `CombinePlots` will only move axes, it will never change the plot range. I will think about a good way to incorporate such alignment of left/right axes positions into the functionality for a future version though.

Comment: How do I get `CombinePlots` and `ResourceFunction`? They are not on my system (Mathematica 11, Windows 7) and although I can see the documentation I don't know how to get the functions. Is this part of Mathematica 12?

Comment: @JackLaVigne Unfortunately, `ResourceFunction` is only available starting from 11.3. But you can get a version of the function by evaluating `PacletInstall@CopyFile[CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/langl/CombinePlots"],CreateDirectory[]<>"/CombinePlots.paclet"]` - this installs a paclet with the `CombinePlots` function. You can then load it using ``<<CombinePlots` ``, and use the function as `CombinePlots[plt1, plt2, ...]`

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with `Inset` and `ImageScaled`.

First, we define your left frame with a specific `ImagePadding` (it is arbitrary but it should be specified so we know what it is):

```
pt1 = Plot[
  1 + Sin[x], {x, 1, 5},
  PlotRange -> {{1, 5}, {0, 3}},
  PlotStyle -> Blue,
  Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}},
  FrameStyle -> {{Blue, None}, {Black, None}},
  ImagePadding -> {{20, 20}, {20, 20}}
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now define the right frame with the same `ImagePadding`:

```
pt2 = Plot[
  80 + 50 Cos[x^2], {x, 1, 5},
  PlotRange -> {{1, 5}, {20, 130}},
  Axes -> None,
  PlotStyle -> Red,
  Frame -> {{False, True}, {False, False}},
  FrameStyle -> {{None, Red}, {Black, None}},
  FrameTicks -> {{None, Range[20, 140, 10]}, {Automatic, None}},
  ImagePadding -> {{20, 20}, {20, 20}}
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now, since they both have the same image padding and no image margins, it should be possible to simply put one on top of the other if we make sure that they have the same size. This is where `ImageScaled` comes in, by using `ImageScaled` we're saying exactly this; that the plot that we use as overlay should have the same size as the first plot.

```
Show[
 pt1,
 Graphics[{
   Inset[
    pt2,
    {Center, Center},
    {Center, Center},
    ImageScaled[{1, 1}]
    ]}
  ],
  PlotRangeClipping -> False
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]