# Combining two ListPlots with different y scales

Tags: plotting

I need to plot two ListPlots on two time-series with different scales, and draw both y axes separately. IE, something like this

[image]

This [resource function](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CombinePlots) provides this functionality for regular `Plot`, but it fails to reposition the second axes for `ListPlot`. Is there a better alternative?

```
combPlot = ResourceFunction["CombinePlots"];
xs = Range[100];
ys1 = xs;
ys2 = 10 xs + 10;
plot1 = ListPlot[Transpose[{xs, ys1}]]
plot2 = ListPlot[Transpose[{xs, ys2}], FrameStyle -> Red, 
  Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Red]
combPlot[plot1, plot2]
```

[image]

Comment: Do the answers to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/210152/combining-two-plots-with-separate-frame-tick-styles) question address the issue.

Comment: The answer say to use CombinePlot resource function, which has the issue described

Comment: Sorry - [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/164846/plot-with-multiple-y-axes) question referenced in the comments has a good answer that doesn't use `CombinePlots`.

Comment: Aha, that indeed solve the issue. TLDR; combine two plots with `Overlay`, and move y-axis to the right using `Frame -> {False, False, False, 
  True}, FrameTicks -> {{False, All}, {False, False}}`

Comment: Your plots do not match the code. Were you using ``ListLogPlot`` for red set of points?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm surprised the easiest result (built-in functionality) was not yet mentioned:

```
xs = Range[100];
ys1 = xs^2;
ys2 = 10 xs + 10;
data1 = Transpose[{xs, ys1}];
data2 = Transpose[{xs, ys2}];
ListPlot[{data1, data2}, MultiaxisArrangement -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: good find, this seems like a new feature in 13

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively,

```
Clear["Global`*"]

xs = Range[100];
ys1 = xs;
ys2 = 10 xs + 10;

ResourceFunction["MultipleAxesListPlot"][
 {Transpose[{xs, ys1}], Transpose[{xs, ys2}]},
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Red},
 "SecondaryAxesColor" -> Red,
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"plot1", "plot2"},
   {.3, .7}]]
```

[image]

```
ResourceFunction["MultipleAxesListPlot"][
 {Transpose[{xs, ys1}], Transpose[{xs, ys2}]},
 Joined -> True,
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, {Red, Dashed}},
 "SecondaryAxesColor" -> Red,
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"plot1", "plot2"},
   {.3, .7}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[`ResourceFunction["CombinePlots"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CombinePlots) does support `ListPlot` (in fact, it should support all 2D plot types, and any combination of them). You are simply missing some options:

```
combPlot = ResourceFunction["CombinePlots"];
xs = Range[100];
ys1 = xs;
ys2 = 10 xs + 10;
plot1 = ListPlot[Transpose[{xs, ys1}], Frame -> True]
plot2 = ListPlot[Transpose[{xs, ys2}], FrameStyle -> Red, 
  Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Red]
combPlot[plot1, plot2, "AxesSides" -> "TwoY"]
```

[image]

First, note the added `Frame->True` option for the first plot: like `Show`, `CombinePlots` will use options from the first plot where applicable, including the `Frame->False` option. Second, note the `"AxesSides" -> "TwoY"` option needed to actually tell `CombinePlots` on which axes to put the individual plots.

Comment: You are right, that does that trick