# How to differently color the two time series using two-Y-axes

Tags: plotting, code-review

I produced the following time series `ListLinePlot`:

[image]

using the following `Code` (thanks to many of the contributors in this forum)

```
q1 = {{2.0779957`*^7, 2.1606992`*^7, 2.2600774`*^7, 2.3680871`*^7, 
    2.4726689`*^7, 2.5654274`*^7, 2.6433058`*^7, 2.7100542`*^7, 
    2.7722281`*^7, 2.8394806`*^7, 2.9185511`*^7, 3.0117411`*^7, 
    3.1161378`*^7, 3.2269592`*^7, 3.3370804`*^7, 3.4413603`*^7, 
    3.5383028`*^7, 3.6296111`*^7, 3.7171922`*^7, 3.8041757`*^7, 
    3.8928341`*^7}};
q2 = {{2.97505722281038`, 3.90280496415438`, 4.4967187466326`, 
    4.66834379545461`, 4.32155951673842`, 3.68269988149014`, 
    2.9905238360968`, 2.49383039084495`, 2.26827304079294`, 
    2.39697830237036`, 2.74661463795293`, 3.14310555651301`, 
    3.40760003260595`, 3.49459192739625`, 3.35560233082199`, 
    3.07705362914441`, 2.77803478841236`, 2.54783303994568`, 
    2.38430907940751`, 2.31307334941778`, 2.30381209309418`}};

qw1 = ListLinePlot[
   q1,
   PlotLabel -> "Afghanistan",
   PlotStyle -> {Thin, Blue},
   ImagePadding -> 25,
   ImageSize -> 500,
   AspectRatio -> 0.4,
   Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}},
   FrameStyle -> {Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Bold], 
     Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Bold, Blue], Automatic, 
     Automatic}
   ];
qw2 = ListLinePlot[
   q2,
   PlotLabel -> "Afghanistan",
   PlotStyle -> {Thin, Red},
   ImagePadding -> 25,
   ImageSize -> 500,
   AspectRatio -> 0.4,
   Axes -> False,
   Frame -> {{False, True}, {False, False}},
   FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}},
   FrameStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, Automatic, 
     Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Bold, Red]}
   ];

Labeled[
 Overlay[{qw1, qw2}],
 Style[#, 14, #2, ShowStringCharacters -> False] & @@@ 
  Transpose[{{Rotate["Population", 90 Degree], 
     Rotate["Population growth rate (%)", 90 Degree], "Years"}, {Blue,
      Red, Black}}], {Left, Right, Bottom}
 ]
```

My purpose is to color the fluctuating series (population growth) with RED but I cannot find where my mistake is.

Comment: try `PlotStyle -> Directive@{Thin, Blue}`  instead of `PlotStyle ->{Thin, Blue}`  (Similarly, `PlotStyle -> Directive@{Thin, Red}`  in the second plot).

Comment: @kglr: When I add `date=Range[2000,2020]` and change the plot `qw1` as `qw1 = ListLinePlot[Transpose@{date, q1},...]` the plot is not working. Why do you think?

Comment: There is an official ["How To"](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/GeneratePlotsWithTwoVerticalScales.html). And if you wait just a bit, there is a new feature [coming up in V13](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RBc8o1tH-3Q), called _multiple axis plots_ :-)

Comment: Similar discussions: [164846](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/164846/plot-with-multiple-y-axes) and [627](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/627/1-plot-2-scale-axis)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the desired result using a single `ListLinePlot` as follows:

```
ListLinePlot[Join[q1, Rescale[q2,  {0, 5}, MinMax @ q1]], 
 Frame -> True,
 PlotStyle -> (Directive[Thin, #] & /@ {Blue, Red}),
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Charting`FindTicks[ MinMax@q1, {0, 5}]}, 
    {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"Population", "Population growth rate (%)"}, {"Year", None}},
 FrameStyle -> {{Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Bold, Blue], 
    Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Bold, Red]}, {Automatic, Automatic}},
 PlotLabel -> "Afganistan",
 ImageSize -> 500,
 AspectRatio -> 0.4]
```

[image]

Comment: Using my original code, I created a `Manipulate` to see for each country the two time series. It works just as expected. However, your `Code` above is much elegant and short, and wanted to use it in a `Manipulate`. Therefore, I prepared a `Manipulate` by simply replacing the corresponding inputs for `q1` with `grjdataWB[countries, var1]` and for `q2` with `grjdataWB[countries, var2]`. The arguments of `grjdataWB[..]` are controls. It does not work and I get an error saying `HeadList and Plus at positions 1 and 2 are to be the same.`

Comment: Wouldn't `{0,5}` be `MinMax@q2`? For some cases, I have no list plot for the RED axis variable, although there are data attached to it.

Comment: Yes. I picked `{0,5}` to get a picture similar to the one in your post.

Answer (score 4):

you can always use `ResourceFunction["CombinePlots"]` in such a case

```
ResourceFunction["CombinePlots"][
 ListLinePlot[q1, PlotLabel -> "Afganistan", ImageSize -> 500, 
  AspectRatio -> 0.4, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Years", "Population", None, None}, 
  FrameStyle -> {Directive[{Blue, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 12}], 
    Directive[{Black, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 12}]}], 
 ListLinePlot[q2, PlotLabel -> "Afganistan", ImageSize -> 500, 
  AspectRatio -> 0.4, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Red, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Years", "Population growth rate (%)", None, None}, 
  FrameStyle -> Directive[{Red, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 12}]], 
 "AxesSides" -> "TwoY"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found out the reason and corrected it as follows:

```
q1 = grjdataWB["Afghanistan", "Population, total"] // Normal // 
   Flatten;
q2 = grjdataWB["Afghanistan", "Population growth (annual %)"] // 
    Normal // Flatten; 
date = Range[2000, 2020];
```

The reason is that data comes from a Mathematica Dataset and therefore needs to be adjusted by `//Normal//Flatten` to get the correct plot with RED color. Although the reason is identified, I think it is better to keep this question as it shows that the data extracted from a Mathematica Dataset should be adjusted if one wants to produce the 2-Y-axes plot as shown.